# "The connection was reset" on FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL with php

Tags: php

I do not find anything on the web and I don't know why: Calling

```
filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

leads to the connection being reset (at least that's what Firefox tells me). The server has PHP version `5.3.13 with Suhosin-Patch` on FreeBSD.
Testing this on my own server which runs Debian and PHP version `5.3.3` also with Suhosin works fine, though I seem to remember it did show the same behaviour before.

PHP manual indicates this was introduced on PHP 5.2.0 so it should work, shouldn't it?

Edit: To better show what fails, I show you two examples, one with reset, the other with a proper `die("message");`

This example outputs `Before validate` on the browser Window:

```
if (function_exists('filter_var')) { //Introduced in PHP 5.2

    die("Before validate");
  if(filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
} else {
return preg_match('/^(?:[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+@(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-](?!\.)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-](?!$)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9_]?)|(?:\[(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\]))$/', $address);
}
```

The example leads to the aforementioned "connection was reset...":

```
if (function_exists('filter_var')) { //Introduced in PHP 5.2


  if(filter_var($address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE) {

  die("After validate");
    return false;
  } else {

  die("After validate");
    return true;
  }
} else {
  return preg_match('/^(?:[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+@(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-](?!\.)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9_](?:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-](?!$)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9_]?)|(?:\[(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\]))$/', $address);
}
```

I do **not** get an output like "After validate" here.
Also the address is a very easy "no-reply@domain.com" address, so its even valid.

Okay another edit: I made a oneliner running only this function and executed it on the console. This is the output:

```
/libexec/ld-elf.so.1: /usr/local/lib/php/20090626/filter.so: Undefined symbol "php_pcre_exec"
```

I handed this over to the server admin. From what I found on google, a simple update could solve it, but I will have to wait for his answer. If the issue is solved, I will note this here. Until then this will have to rest, as I cannot fix such a system-deep error.

Comment: And without that line it works? Please show us the rest of the code. This sounds highly unlikely.

Comment: This issue occurs if calling Joomla code, but with some die(); before and after functions I traced this down. I will post you exactly what will and what won't die in my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this [suhosin](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/updates/11.3/x86_64/php5-suhosin-5.3.3-0.17.1.x86_64.html) summary they talk about a fix to a segfault when using that flag, it's an opensuse report but it might be that your install is susceptible to it. You'll probably need to make sure that your suhosin patch is up to at least what corresponds to opensuse's version 0.17.1. Problem is I can't find anything about it on suhosin's official [changelog](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/updates/11.3/x86_64/php5-suhosin-5.3.3-0.17.1.x86_64.html). Where does freebsd get their port source from in this case?

> - Tue Oct 26 2010 pgajdos@novell.com
>
>   - fix "Segfault in filter_var with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL with
>       large amount of data" [bnc#649210]
>   - CVE-2010-3710.patch

Comment: Thank you, this might actually be related. See my above edit, maybe this is exactly the issue fixed. Since I am not a FreeBSD user, I cannot answer your question with accurately but the problem file was installed by php5-filter-5.3.13 is was pkg_info states.

Comment: well, please let us know should you resolve this, you never know when it might be helpful for someone else. :)

Comment: according to my admin a complete update had to be done. Old directories had to be completely removed (renamed) and a fresh install was necessary, since old libraries were in the way. I will accept your answer, because it is likely to have cause the issue, though the actual solution was a plain, clean re-install.